# iOS 7 Inline DatePicker - Not appearing inside cell bounds

Tags: ios7, uitableview

I've incorporated the [Apple provided sample code (DateCell)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html) for displaying a PickerView inline into my previous code for my uitableview. What's happening is that the pickerView is being rendered well outside of the tableviewcell's bounds...

Anyone have any ideas as to why my cell content is not displayed in the cell bounds?

I've even removed the picker view and used a label to test, same thing happens. It's clearly something going on with the cell contentView - I just can't seem to lock it down...

Screenshot (before clicking to reveal the date picker):

[image]

Problem Screenshot (after clicking to reveal the date picker):

[image]

Problem V2 Screenshot:
(with cell clips bounds to YES)

[image]

Storyboard Layout Screenshot:
(cell has green background for visibility)

[image]

Storyboard Layout Outline Screenshot:

[image]

Code:

**ECNAddSessionViewController.h**

```
@interface ECNAddSessionViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

**ECNAddSessionViewController.m - category extension**

```
@interface ECNAddSessionViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Session *session;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

// keep track which indexPath points to the cell with UIDatePicker
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *datePickerIndexPath;
@property (assign) NSInteger pickerCellRowHeight;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *pickerView;

// this button appears only when the date picker is shown (iOS 6.1.x or earlier)
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;

- (void)commonSetup;
- (void)registerForNotifications;
- (void)deregisterForNotifications;

- (IBAction)cancelAction:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)saveAction:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

**CommonSetup Method**

```
- (void)commonSetup {

    //initialize our Session
    self.session = [[Session alloc] init];

    self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle]; // show short-style date format
    [self.dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    // obtain the picker view cell's height, works because the cell was pre-defined in our storyboard
    UITableViewCell *pickerViewCellToCheck = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kECNAddSessionDatePickerCellIdentifier];
    self.pickerCellRowHeight = pickerViewCellToCheck.frame.size.height;
}
```

**Apple Provided Sample Code Methods - Slightly Adjusted**

```
/*! Determines if the given indexPath has a cell below it with a UIDatePicker.

 @param indexPath The indexPath to check if its cell has a UIDatePicker below it.
 */
- (BOOL)hasPickerForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BOOL hasDatePicker = NO;

    NSInteger targetedRow = indexPath.row;
    targetedRow++;

    UITableViewCell *checkDatePickerCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:targetedRow inSection:0]];
    UIDatePicker *checkDatePicker = (UIDatePicker *)[checkDatePickerCell viewWithTag:kDatePickerTag];

    hasDatePicker = (checkDatePicker != nil);
    return hasDatePicker;
}

/*! Updates the UIDatePicker's value to match with the date of the cell above it.
 */
- (void)updateDatePicker {

    if (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil) {

        UITableViewCell *associatedDatePickerCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.datePickerIndexPath];

        UIDatePicker *targetedDatePicker = (UIDatePicker *)[associatedDatePickerCell viewWithTag:kDatePickerTag];

        if (targetedDatePicker != nil) {

            // we found a UIDatePicker in this cell, so update it's date value
            if (self.session.date) {

                [targetedDatePicker setDate:self.session.date animated:NO];
            }
        }
    }
}

/*! Determines if the UITableViewController has a UIDatePicker in any of its cells.
 */
- (BOOL)hasInlineDatePicker {

    return (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil);
}

/*! Determines if the given indexPath points to a cell that contains the UIDatePicker.

 @param indexPath The indexPath to check if it represents a cell with the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (BOOL)indexPathHasPicker:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return ([self hasInlineDatePicker] && self.datePickerIndexPath.row == indexPath.row);
}

/*! Determines if the given indexPath points to a cell that contains the start/end dates.

 @param indexPath The indexPath to check if it represents start/end date cell.
 */
- (BOOL)indexPathHasDate:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BOOL hasDate = NO;

    if ((indexPath.row == kDateStartRow) || [self hasInlineDatePicker]) {

        hasDate = YES;
    }

    return hasDate;
}

/*! Adds or removes a UIDatePicker cell below the given indexPath.

 @param indexPath The indexPath to reveal the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (void)toggleDatePickerForSelectedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    NSArray *indexPaths = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:0]];

    // check if 'indexPath' has an attached date picker below it
    if ([self hasPickerForIndexPath:indexPath]) {

        // found a picker below it, so remove it
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }else {

        // didn't find a picker below it, so we should insert it
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

**Display Inline Date Picker Method**

In Number of Sections, I hardcoded 1 - to have just one section like Apple's sample code, even though ultimately the tableview will have three

```
/*! Reveals the date picker inline for the given indexPath, called by "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".

 @param indexPath The indexPath to reveal the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (void)displayInlineDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // display the date picker inline with the table content
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    BOOL before = NO;   // indicates if the date picker is below "indexPath", help us determine which row to reveal
    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker]) {

        before = self.datePickerIndexPath.row < indexPath.row;
    }

    BOOL sameCellClicked = (self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1 == indexPath.row);

    // remove any date picker cell if it exists
    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker]) {

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.datePickerIndexPath.row inSection:0]]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        self.datePickerIndexPath = nil;
    }

    if (!sameCellClicked) {

        // hide the old date picker and display the new one
        NSInteger rowToReveal = (before ? indexPath.row - 1 : indexPath.row);
        NSIndexPath *indexPathToReveal = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToReveal inSection:0];

        [self toggleDatePickerForSelectedIndexPath:indexPathToReveal];
        self.datePickerIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPathToReveal.row + 1 inSection:0];
    }

    // always deselect the row containing the start or end date
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    // inform our date picker of the current date to match the current cell
    [self updateDatePicker];
}
```

**UITableViewDataSource Methods**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return ([self indexPathHasPicker:indexPath] ? self.pickerCellRowHeight : self.tableView.rowHeight);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1; //attempted to limit sections to just one (like Apple Sample Code)
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSInteger rows = 0;

    switch (section) {
        case AddSessionBasicInfoSection:

            //return three cells
            // name
            // company
            // date
            rows = 3;

            if ([self hasInlineDatePicker]) {

                // we have a date picker, so allow for it in the number of rows in this section
                return ++rows;
            }

            break;
        case AddSessionTagsSection:

            //return one cell
            rows = 1;
            break;
        case AddSessionContentSection:

            //return dynamic number of cells + the add content cell
            rows = 1;//TODO: Make Dynamic, Build Add Content feature
            break;
    }

    return rows;
}
```

**Cell Configuration**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case AddSessionBasicInfoSection:

            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0: // session name cell
                {
                    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kECNAddSessionSessionNameCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
                }
                    break;
                case 1: //company name cell
                {
                    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kECNAddSessionCompanyNameCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

                }
                    break;
                case 2: // date cell
                {
                    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kECNAddSessionDateCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

                    // we have either start or end date cells, populate their date field
                    cell.textLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.session.date];
                }
                    break;
                case 3: // date picker cell
                {
                    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kECNAddSessionDatePickerCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

                    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
                }
                    break;

            }
            break;
        case AddSessionTagsSection:

            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kECNAddSessionAddTagsCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            break;
        case AddSessionContentSection:

            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kECNAddSessionAddContentCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

**Cell Selection**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.reuseIdentifier == kECNAddSessionDateCellIdentifier) {

        if (EMBEDDED_DATE_PICKER) {

            [self displayInlineDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }else {

            [self displayExternalDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
    }else{

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, I feel stupid since it was as simple as the **cell wasn't getting any height value** Should have found this earlier...

I was asking for the height from my `datePickerCell` in my `- (void)commonSetup;` method by dequeueing the cell and grabbing its `frame.size.height` too early.

I had to move the code below from `- (void)awakFromNib;` By moving the code to `- (void)viewDidLoad;`

```
// obtain the picker view cell's height, works because the cell was pre-defined in our storyboard
    UITableViewCell *pickerViewCellToCheck = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kECNAddSessionDatePickerCellIdentifier];
    self.pickerCellRowHeight = pickerViewCellToCheck.frame.size.height;
```

Turns out `self.tableView` is still `nil` when `awakeFromNib` was calling `commonSetup`